# code with getInputStream() was compatible with Java 1.6, but is anymore with 1.7

Tags: java

I have a piece of software which establishes a communication between a PC and a machine, which used to work in Java 1.6, but doesn't anymore in 1.7. The IOException --> "Invalid Http response" is what I get as soon as the getInputStream() method is called. It seems like the method had been improved an is much more sensitive, meaning that responseCode=
-1 result is not specifically checked in Java 1.6.

Assited with Wireshark I checked if both versions (1.6 & 1.7) sent and received same Ethernet frames, and so did both.

I can only resolve this from the PC (client) side...that means no posibility to edit or change the Server code.

I would apreciate any help on how to modify or implement something new to make the code compatible for ver. 1.7 as Im not a former programmer... Thanks

**Sequence:**

1. get is called
2. return readResponse(..) is called
3. getInputStream() --> IOException
4. catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("error sending get request " + getURL() + " string: " + requestString); return Error.ethernetException; //TODO

**here the console output:**

-1
error sending get request ... string: *APPLETCOMMINFO_
strResponse: Ethernet Exception

**and the Code:**

```
private String get(String requestString)/* throws ComunicationException*/ {
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    OutputStream out = null;        

    try {   
        String encodedRequestString = URLEncoder.encode(requestString, "iso-8859-1");
        String path = getURL().getPath();
        if (!path.endsWith("/")) path = path + "/";
        path = path + encodedRequestString;
        URL fullURL = new URL(getURL().getProtocol(), getURL().getHost(), getURL().getPort(), path);
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)fullURL.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(false);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Set timeout at 5s
        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(m_nTimeOut);
        httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(m_nTimeOut);

        return readResponse(httpURLConnection);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error sending get request " + getURL() + " string: " + requestString);
        return Error.ethernetException; //TODO
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("GET: out.close(), Class: Client");
            }
        }

        if (httpURLConnection != null) {
            try {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("GET: httpURLConnection.disconnect(), Class: Client");
            }
        }
    }       
}

/**
 * Reads the response from the server into a string.
 * The content length header must be set!
 * @param connection
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
private String readResponse(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
    if (connection == null) throw new IllegalStateException("connection must not be null");

     connection.connect();

    int status = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(status);

    // InputStream aaa = connection.getInputStream();


    Reader reader = null;
    try {           
        reader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1");

        int readBufferSize = connection.getContentLength();
        if (readBufferSize < 0) {
            // use default buffer size
            readBufferSize = DEFAULT_READ_BUFFER_SIZE;
        }

        // if content length was set, read will be done in a single 
        // iteration because buffer fits... 
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        char[] readBuffer = new char[readBufferSize];
        int len;
        while ((len = reader.read(readBuffer)) > 0) {
            response.append(new String(readBuffer, 0, len));                    
        }
        return response.toString();



    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw ioe;      
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("readResponse: reader.close(), Class: Client");
                //log
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @return the url
 */
public URL getURL() {
    return url;
}
```

}

Comment: The exception is being thrown from within your `readResponse` method. Can you include that code? Also, you should print the exceptions stack trade (if you haven't already), and include it in your question.

Comment: readResponse is already within the code, just need to scroll a bit down... =)